# How to run a program against many arguments as files from a folder

Tags: java, eclipse, args

This is the basic layout of the program I have:

```
public class myClass {

    public void run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // do something with the file
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new myClass().run(args);
    }
}
```

The arguments I set in eclipse are file locations on my drive, and while I can duplicate the run configurations and add every file I want to run against, that's not a very efficient method if I have hundreds of files, and even less so if the files regularly change. What I'd like, ideally, is to be able to specify a folder, and have my program run for every file in the folder that has a certain extension, say ".txt". Is this possible in eclipse or do I have to write a script to achieve this or something else? If a script is needed, some tips on how would be much appreciated since I'm not well versed in script-writing.

Comment: You do not tell what the purpose of your program is. Start with that...

Comment: Yes, you can retrieve file names in a particular directory in your Java code.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/dirs.html#listdir

Comment: Create a [FileVisitor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitor.html) and go through the files in the directory, then check against the extension. Look at the [Java IO API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like so:

```
public class myClass implements FileFilter {

        public void run(File[] files) throws Exception {
            // do something with the file
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            File folder = new File(folderPathString);
            new myClass().run(folder.listFiles(new myClass()));
        }

        public boolean accept(File pathname) {
            return pathname.getName().endsWith(".txt");
        }
    }
```